# Trying to set filteredItemsCollection from ng-repeat inside ng-if prevents parent scope from inheriting the value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I've got an ng-repeat nested within an ng-if block:

`<div ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (fullItemCollection | filter:searchQuery)>{{item}}</div>`

When I try to access $scope.filteredItems from my controller, I don't see the filteredItems as they should be.  I'm assuming it's something to do with the scope that's created by ng-if, but I'm pretty sure I've used similar setups before without any problems.

Made a jsfiddle as a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gLdeM/

Also made a jsfiddle to show that this behavior indeed works without the ng-if: http://jsfiddle.net/LgSAL/1/

note: I know plnkr's all the rage, but for some reason our firewall is blocking saving on plnkr :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that javascript inheritance is primarily meant for javascript objects.  If I nest the full and filtered arrays in an outer object, it works.

```
$scope.items = {
    filtered: [],
    full: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue-green', 'yellow-green', 'orange']
};
```

See [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLdeM/5/)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `filteredItems` is just locally available within the `ng-repeat`. If you want to filter the second list in the same way as the first list use the same filter condition:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (fullItems | filter:searchQuery)">
  {{ item }}
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gLdeM/1/

Comment: Looking to see if I can find another example, but I swear I've used it before in order to get the filteredItems array in the scope that the ng-repeat lives in.  Standby for jsfiddle XD

Comment: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LgSAL/1/) jsfiddle.  I commented out the ng-if, and made it so the 2nd ng-repeat is referencing the filteredItems array that's initialized in the parent scope from the first ng-repeat.

Comment: The issue is that I need the filteredItems array in the parent scope, so that I could potentially do stuff to that array from within my controller.